# Multirow & multicolumn problem

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow

How do I take out that little vertical line underneath "this"??? Where do i have to fix it? Also how to adjust spacing between the rows?

[image]

`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c | }
    \cline{1-7}
        \multirow{3}{*}{State} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{this}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{This work  } \\ 
        \cline {4-7} 
        { } & {} & {} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{real} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{complex} \\
        \cline{2-7}
    {} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
             \cline{1-7}
     $2$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     $2$ & 1 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 5 \\
    \cline{1-7}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) rather than just small chunks of code. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the vertical line below "this" you just put `\multicolumn2{c|}{}` into the second line of your tabular environment.

Having said this, there are good typographical reasons not to use vertical rules in your tables at all: see the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual for a discussion of this issue. For these reasons I recommend removing all of the vertical rules from your table. For comparison, here is your table together with a second version that uses horizontal rules from [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

Of course, you should use whichever version you think is better!

Here is the updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c | }
\cline{1-7}
    \multirow{3}{*}{States} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{this}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{This work  } \\
    \cline {4-7}
    { } & \multicolumn2{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{real-range} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{complex-range} \\
    \cline{2-7}
{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
         \cline{1-7}
 $2^{-}$ & 0.798 & 0.648 & 0.74 & 0.59 & 0.78 & 0.60 \\
 $2^{-}$ & 1.27 & 5.57 & 2.10 & 5.82 & 2.05 & 5.60 \\
\cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ *7c }\toprule
    \multirow{3}{*}{States} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{This}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{This work  } \\
    \cmidrule {4-7}
     & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{real-range} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{complex-range} \\
    \midrule
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
   \midrule
   $2^{-}$ & 0.798 & 0.648 & 0.74 & 0.59 & 0.78 & 0.60 \\
   $2^{-}$ & 1.27 & 5.57 & 2.10 & 5.82 & 2.05 & 5.60 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The  advantage of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule`, over the standard `\hline` and `\cline`,  is that they have slightly different widths.

Comment: Oh god thank you so much! I was trying to fix/add some stuff as you advised. Will post full mini examples from now on. Have a good day :)

Comment: @Mico Thanks, you're right of course. I've taken them out.

Comment: I would take rid of `\multirow` altogether; there's no point in making such a stair-shaped pattern if you adopt `booktabs` rules; probably there should be a `\cmidrule(lr){2-3}` below “This”, which also requires `\cmidrule(l){4-7}` below “This work”.